# What to Use Instead of QWebEngineView for PyQt 5.6 with Anaconda 3

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5

I am using plotly to generate HTML code I then use QWebEngineView to view. This worked fine before I tried to go over to Anaconda 3. Based on some searching, this is because Anaconda's PyQt distribution is behind the actual current distribution (which I used to originally write the code). What would be the correct way to make a widget that I can set the HTML of in QWebKit, which is what Anaconda's PyQt comes with? It's also okay to say that I shouldn't be using Anaconda. I prefer it primarily for the libraries it comes with (I'm not using the enterprise version) but could also get them for the Python 3.6 I'm already using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QtWebKit` provides the [`QWebView`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebview.html) widget, that can be used in much the same way as `QWebEngineView`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebKitWidgets

html = '''<body>
            <b>Hello world!</b>
          </body>'''

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
webview = QtWebKitWidgets.QWebView()
webview.setHtml(html)
webview.show()
app.exec_()
```

You could also take a look at [`cefpython`](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/releases) for a Chromium based browser widget that can be [embedded in a `PyQt` GUI](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/blob/master/examples/qt.py) regardless of version. It's a little heavyweight, but I have found it to be much faster than `QtWebkit`. I'm not sure if it's available for Anaconda however.